# The naming of the [downcasting] and [up-casting] tags is inconsistent

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-synonym-process

There was a recent question that was tagged with both [downcasting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/downcasting) and [up-casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/up-casting). My immediate thought was that one of these should be renamed to be consistent with the other (either both hyphenated or both not), but the solution seems subjective to me as "downcasting" is arguably a single word and so shouldn't be hyphenated.

Since hyphens don't seem to be significant when searching for a tag, should I even care?

Comment: I can understand it could be a problem when you are looking for questions using a tag, and you don't know if the tag uses the hyphen or not, but it would be a problem if you are looking for questions searching for 3 or more tags at the same time. Even in this case, it's enough to first check what tags the site is using.

Answer (score 1):

My initial reaction to this was, essentially, to wonder why it even matters. However, two things happened. First, I came around to your viewpoint that [up-casting] is just plain wrong. Not only because it doesn't match [downcasting], but more importantly, because "upcasting" is a word—and not even just in computer science jargon. It's actually just [a regular old English word](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/upcast) (albeit a fairly unpopular one in standard usage). The hyphen is incorrect. Second, I realized I have these magic moderator privileges now that make quick work of simple tasks like this.

Therefore, I've gone ahead and renamed the [up-casting] tag to [upcasting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/upcasting). This should have minimal to no impact, other than making things a tiny bit more correct and consistent.

Note, though, that tags in searches are *heavily* cached. It will take some time for this change to become visible. At the time of submission, the [up-casting] tag still appears to be the one used, even though it isn't.

As for the "Are there other tags like this?" question you had originally posed, I'm going to have to declare that too broad. If you come across other tags that bother you on similar grounds, then feel free to bring them to the community's attention via Meta. But I don't think it's worth our time to go hunting for them.